# Please help identify this streaming video protocol

Tags: video-streaming, protocols, rtp

I have been trying to decode the below video stream that comes from an IP camera with WireShark. I have tried to decode as RTP but keep getting an invalid packet. Actually I do not even think it is RTP now.

This is all transported via UDP I have pulled just the data. The long line is sent by the IP camera in question, the short lines are returned from the server. This is 8 packets out of a continuous stream. What I know of the system this data is not encrypted.

I can see what I think is a sequence number B8, B9, Ba, BB and so on. That's as far as I have got. Any help identifying the protocol would be very much appreciated. R.N

```
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
80626D5DB900
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
80626E5DBA00
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
80626F5DBB00
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
8062705DBC00
```

If I assume RTP it does not seem to fit. First the version is 0, and what would be the time stamp does not go up. PT alternates between two dynamic types.

```
RTP
Version 0, Padding 0, Extension 0, CSRC = 0

   PT [SN ] [timestamp] [SSRC     ]
00 78 5D B8 17 EA 92 70 20 2C 0E 08
00 77 5D B9 17 63 92 80 18 20 0B 08
00 77 5D BA 17 DB 92 80 20 24 06 89
00 78 5D BB 17 52 94 70 30 18 05 08
```

Answer (score 0):

> 80626D5DB900
>
> 80626E5DBA00
>
> 80626F5DBB00
>
> 8062705DBC00

These seems to be the start of the RTP header. You see there is an incremental sequence 0x6D 0x6E 0x6F 0x70. One question, is this the wireshark packet capture?

Comment: Yes I pulled the data payload of each UDP packet and exported it.